# Port Forwarding not working on cellular data but working on wifi

Tags: port-forwarding, tcp

I recently developed a web app using Express and Node.js and I am hosting it locally on my PC. I set up my router to port forward HTTP requests to the web app to my PC. It works fine whenever the client (even clients on different networks than mine) connecting to it using (my-public-ip):3000 is on a Wi-Fi network, however it doesn't work using cellular 4G data. Why could this be? I have used Wireshark to view the traffic. When using 4G, the router forwards the HTTP requests to the PC and I receive them and send back HTTP responses, but the client never receives them. Why are they getting lost or what's happening exactly?

Comment: Hmm, if Wireshark on your LAN sees the HTTP request come in from the external 4G client, that means two-way traffic must be working, because the TCP 3-way handshake must have worked. How big are your HTTP responses? If they're over, say 1300 bytes, you might be running into a Path MTU Discovery black hole between you and the 4G wireless carrier's network. You might try lowering your web app PC's interface MTU down from 1500 to, say, 1300, and see if that fixes it. If it does, try raising your MTU back up in increments until you find the maximum value that works.

Comment: @Spiff The html responses are very basic html pages (728 bytes) exactly, so I do not think that's the issue. What's very intriguing to me is the fact the TCP 3-way handshake did work indeed, I am really curious to find out why the client is not getting these responses.